# Concatenate different rows data

Tags: sql-server

Could you please suggest an approach to get the logic for below

Note: This logic needs to be added for existing JOIN query, which I have finished already.

Question: Table name: T_FULL_DETAILS, Database: SQL Server

**The expectation is**

```
select DESCRIPTION from T_FULL_DETAILS WHERE SEQ_ID=3
```

then it should return "Hellooo.. Good morning Good Afternoon Good evenin"

```
select DESCRIPTION from T_FULL_DETAILS WHERE SEQ_ID=5
```

then it should return "This is last record Five "

So here the `TEXT_IDX` doesn't have any fixed limit. Could you check and help me to write the relevant query in SQL Server?

Reference data is below

[image]

Comment: SEQ_ID TEXT_IDX DESCRIPTION
3 1 Hellooo..
3 2 Good morning
3 3 Good Afternoon
3 4 Good evenin
4 1 my number
4 2 four
5 1 This is
5 2 last record
5 3 Five

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: Marc Guillot's comment pretty much answers the question with different ways to acheive this. But you should really do stuff like concatenating query results client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the function [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to aggregate text fields.

```
select string_agg(DESCRIPTION, ' ') from T_FULL_DETAILS where SEQ_ID=3
```

Please notice that this function is only available since SQL Server 2016, if you are using a previous version then you need to find an alternative, like using the XML features:

```
select DESCRIPTION + ' ' as DESCRIPTION 
from T_FULL_DETAILS 
where SEQ_ID=3 
order by TEXT_IDX
for XML path('')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. it returns string_agg is not a recognized built-in function name. I am working on SQL 2008. Any alternative for this ?

Comment: @Johnny Hi Johnny, I've added an alternative for older versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version you can use one of the following:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(DESCRIPTION, ' ') WITHIN  GROUP (ORDER BY TEXT_IDX ASC)
FROM T_FULL_DETAILS
WHERE SEQ_ID=3

SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        select ' ' + DESCRIPTION  AS DESCRIPTION 
        from T_FULL_DETAILS 
        where SEQ_ID=3 
        ORDER BY TEXT_IDX
        for XML path('')
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,1
    ,''
);
```

Note, that important part here is to `ORDER BY` the concatenation values by `TEXT_IDX`.

Comment: perfect. This saves lots of time for me today. Thank you very much